# Coherence time of beams from broadband FT instruments?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, coherence

To determine whether incident and reflected waves interfere within a film, we have to consider whether the coherence time of the beam is less than the travel time of the beam in the film. (This is the motivation for my question.)

The coherence time $\tau$ is defined by the spectral width or spectral bandwidth $\Delta \lambda$ [[ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_time)]:
\begin{equation}
\tau = 1/\Delta \nu \approx \frac{\lambda^2}{c\Delta\lambda}
\end{equation}
where $\nu$ is the frequency and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

For signals from an Fourier Transform instrument (broadband radiation passed through an interferometer), what is the effective spectral bandwidth? In [this](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Fourier_Transform_Infrared_Spectrometry.html?id=ZecrNiUkHToC) book, the "spectral bandwidth" seems to correspond to the entire broadband range: "at wavenumbers greater than approximately 6400 cm$^{-1}$ and less than 450 cm$^{-1}$ for mid-infrared measurements". But I would think that for the purpose of estimating coherence time, it would have to be related to the spectral resolution?

Comment: What do you mean by *spectral resolution*?  The resolution of the spectrometer?

Comment: @garyp yes that's what I mean, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_infrared_spectroscopy#Resolution

Comment: Actually, I had a different sense of *resolution* in mind, but your link clears up what you mean.